# Unicorn and Rails eat up 2x MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, unicorn

I run 10 Unicorn workers for each server and they eat up all MySQL connections over time, ending up with "too many connections" error. It starts out with 10 connections, but gradually increase up to 20.

When I run the following script on production (using `SHOW PROCESSLIST`), I can see that each IP (= app server) has 20 connections each, where it should be 10 - excatly double the number of Unicorn workers.

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'show processlist'
result.group_by{|i| i[2].split(':').first }.map{|k,v| [k, v.size] }
 => [["192.168.1.2", 20], ["192.168.1.3", 20], ["192.168.1.4", 20], ... ]
```

Here's the database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  ...
  pool: 1
```

Here's the netstat:

```
# netstat -an | grep :3306
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:58535   192.168.1.123:3306    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:45021   192.168.1.123:3306    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:58537   192.168.1.123:3306    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:45119   192.168.1.123:3306    TIME_WAIT
...

# netstat -an | grep :3306 | wc -l
36
# netstat -an | grep :3306 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
33
```

I'm worried that there's a few `TIME_WAIT` - it shouldn't be there as the connections should be all persistent - it seems that the worker has more connections than necessary. Plenty of free RAM, no swap / OOM.

Ruby 2.0.0p0 / Rails 3.2.13

What's causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, thanks to [@ono](http://twitter.com/ono)'s advice, I found the cause was that [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) agent created its own connection in `NewRelic::Agent::Database::ConnectionManager#get_connection`.

https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/blob/3.5.8.72/lib/new_relic/agent/database.rb#L158

This code calls `ActiveRecord::Base.mysql2_connection`, which in turn calls `Mysql2::Client.new`, which doesn't respect the connection pool settings.

It only occurs when there's slow transactions (ironically though, this code overloads the database even more), so edited `newrelic.yml`

```
transaction_tracer:
  explain_enabled: false
```

and the problem has been solved! I'll keep it that way until New Relic fixes this issue.

Comment: I work at New Relic on the Ruby agent, and wanted to let you know we've improved this behavior in our last release (3.6.0.78 released yesterday).  There was an issue where these DB connections weren't being cleaned up properly under some forking webservers (e.g. Unicorn, Passenger).  We've confirmed that isn't the case anymore.  I think that your point about not honoring the connection pool setting may still stand.  There are some situations (e.g. apps talking to multiple dbs through different adapters) that make that difficult to do, but it's something we'll look into for our next release.

Comment: I updated my gem to 3.6.0.78 and check number of connection there is no change. again lots of connection to mysql. I am using unicorn.

Comment: 3.6.0.78 fixed the problem for me. It still creates connections, just closes them as appropriate. If you have a lot of slow queries concurrently, there will be up to 2x connections. To fix that, New Relic needs to support connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, do you have a middle ware that opens connections to your DB server ? run `$ rake middleware` to verify, sidekiq for example your be a cause, or any other coponent that need its own connections to your DB server

Comment: Good point. I just ran `rake middleware` but it's almost default and couldn't find anything unusual except Airbrake and NewRelic.