# MySQL connections are not closing in rails on heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, connection

I have a rails project deployed to heroku with 1 resque background worker running.  Each time the worker processed a job, the database connection stays open for 90 seconds before closing (the jobs take a few seconds (2 or 3) to process).  When I have lots of jobs to process, I quickly run out of available database connections.  My environment is as follows:

- Rails 3.2.13
- ClearDB mysql database with 15 available connections
- 2 web dynos
- 1 worker dyno using resque
- Unicorn (2 processes per dyno, timeout set to 60)
- In an initializer I set the connection pool to 2 and the reaping frequency to 5
- newrelic (3.6.2.96)

I found another post saying it may be newrelic getting connections and not closing them properly ([Unicorn and Rails eat up 2x MySQL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536159/unicorn-and-rails-eat-up-2x-mysql-connections)), however I tried the suggestion and it didn't make a difference for me.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Have you followed these guides: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn - take a look under Caveats, it shows an example of a unicorn + resque config.

Comment: @mind.blank, I did follow the heroku dev guide and my unicorn config file is pretty much what they list on that page (including the resque part).

Comment: In case someone finds this and has the same problem, I fixed it by switching to using sidekiq instead of resque.  I'm not sure if it had something to do with resque, or just my configuration of it, but sidekiq is working well!